# Case statement in Pandas to transform column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count all `product_id's` per region grouped by month.
Before doing that I need to map the zip code to the region using the duct below:

```
regiondict = {
 "10": "A",
  "23": "A",
  "24": "A",
 "53": "B",
  "32": "B",
  "49": "B",
 "11": "C",
  "14": "C",
  "65": "C"
}
```

Main df

```
product_id    zip_code  month
32324         10        Feb-2019
34345         23        Feb-2019
45453         24        March-2019
34343         53        Feb-2019
53533         32        March-2019
12334         49        March-2019
99934         11        Feb-2019
21213         14        Feb-2019
13232         65        March-2019
```

Output df

```
region    count_product_id  month
A         2                 Feb-2019
A         1                 March-2019
B         1                 Feb-2019
B         2                 March-2019
B         2                 Feb-2019
B         1                 March-2019
```

Comment: yes it is a dictionary with the zip code as the value and the region as the pair

Comment: show us the dict ~

Comment: I have added the dict to the question above

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can do `map` with `groupby` `count`, plus some cosmetic after.

```
df_ = (df.groupby([df.zip_code.astype(str).map(regiondict), 'month'])
          ['product_id'].count()
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'zip_code':'region'}))

print(df_)
  region       month  product_id
0      A    Feb-2019           2
1      A  March-2019           1
2      B    Feb-2019           1
3      B  March-2019           2
4      C    Feb-2019           2
5      C  March-2019           1
```

Comment: @Ben.T you can edit :-) this is community wiki answer :-)

Comment: done :) I saw recently that one can do that community wiki, first time but I think it is great for this kind of question